# Sumar valores desde MOngoDB y Nodejs

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

Muy Buenas a todos. Muchas gracias por su valiosa colaboracion
Tengo el siguiente codigo y no tengo idea de como sumar los valores que obtengo desde MongoDB

```
    adminCtrl.ventastotales = async function(req, res){
  await Orden.find({despacho: "ConDespacho"}, function (error, ordens){
    if(error){
      return res.write("!Error")
    }
    var carro;     
    ordens.forEach(function (orden){
      carro = new Carro(orden.carro)
      orden.items = carro.generarArreglo(); 
      orden.fechas = format(orden.fecha, 'es_ES')       
      //Se lista todos los Valores y se muestra correctamente en la consola
      console.log(carro.totalPrecio)
    });         
    res.render("Inicio", {ordens})   
  })
}
```

La consola efectivamente me muestra cada valor
[image: aqui la consola]

Como hago para poder sumar estos valores en un solo total

de antemano muchas gracias

Comment: Puedes intentar usar el método reduce para ´carro.totalPrecio´ https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reduce.asp

Comment: ¿Qué variables quieres sumar, en qué variable quieres guardar la suma y qué enviarás a la vista (cliente)?. Tal como te recomiendan, puedes usar el método [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce) del tipo `Array` de Javascript.

Comment: @g.4 ya lo intente con reduce(), pero no se como incluirla dentro de la function(orden); estoy usando

Comment: var number = carro.totalPrecio      
      console.log(number.reduce(function(total, num){
        return total + Math.round(num)
      }))

Comment: y de mil maneras mas pero siempre sale "error reduce() no es una funcion"

Comment: Parece que estas recibiendo para cada forEach un ítem del arreglo carro.totalPrecio, puedes confirmar?